# Selenium after clicking load more i cant get the newly loaded content

Tags: python, selenium

I am working on a project where am required to fetch data from a site using selenium.

The website has a `load more` clickable div.

i have managed to make selenium click the `div` and it works you can see it do the clicking when its running on `none --headless mode`

> However when i try to get all the items i don't get the newly loaded
>   items after clicking.

**Here is my code snippet**

```
driver.get('https://jamboshop.com/search/tv')
i=1
maximum=4
while i<maximum:
    try:
        i += 1
        el=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.showMoreLoaderPanel")
        action=ActionChains(driver)
        action.move_to_element(el).click().perform()
        driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    except:
        break

products =driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.col-xs-6.col-sm-4.col-md-4.col-lg-3")
for product in products:
   print({"item_name":product.find_element_by_css_selector("h6.prd-title").text})
```

This only prints the `items` that were present before the clicks...how do i get all the items in the page including ones loaded after clicking `load more`?

**extra**

```
# My imports and chrome settings

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1420,1080')
#chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: Have you considered waiting until the elements appear after clicking load more?

Comment: i am waiting for `3 seconds` in `driver.implicitly_wait(3)` after clicking or a sleep would be much more effective?

Comment: I think you should try waiting for the element you want to be visible.

Comment: @Sr i introduced `time.sleep(3)` seems to be effective i thought `driver.implicitly_wait()` was the more recommended but definitely failed me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a lazy loading application.So when go bottom of the page it seems lost the previous elements it has capture and that is why you can see only current elements on the page available.

There is an alternative way to handle this by checking with a list and then capture those data while iterating the while loop.

**Code**:

```
import time
driver.get('https://jamboshop.com/search/tv')
i=1
maximum=4
itemlist=[]
while i<maximum:
    try:
        products = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.col-xs-6.col-sm-4.col-md-4.col-lg-3")
        for product in products:
            if product.find_element_by_css_selector("h6.prd-title").text in itemlist:
                continue
            else:
                itemlist.append(product.find_element_by_css_selector("h6.prd-title").text)
        i += 1
        el=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.showMoreLoaderPanel")
        action=ActionChains(driver)
        action.move_to_element(el).click().perform()
        time.sleep(3)

    except:
        break

print(len(itemlist))
print(itemlist)
```

Let me know if this works for you.Website is not accessible at my end.

Comment: yes it did work...i think `driver.implicitly_wait(3)` was the issue after i introduced `time.sleep` in my code it collected more items. Also your code is buggy after the new edit..the loop will collect duplicates..that's why in my code i did the clicking first. then collecting the data

Comment: It shouldn’t collect duplicates.I wonder if you see if condition if item present in list continue else append.

Comment: sorry yes it doesn't collect duplicate..my bad.